# How to save String values in spinner with sharedpreference

Tags: java, android, spinner, shared, preference

How to save and load String values ​​in spinner with sharedpreference
1. can not store the value
2. can not load value

array

```
<string-array name="country_array">
    <item>Greece</item>
    <item>United Kingdom</item>
    <item>Italy</item>
    <item>France</item>
    <item>Germany</item>
    <item>Turkey</item>
    <item>Poland</item>
    <item>India</item>
</string-array>
```

Main.java

```
public class SaveSpinShared extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    String getList, loadedList;
    String save;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.save_spin);

        SavePreferences("LIST", "France");

        // load
        LoadPreferences();
        getList = loadedList;

        Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.SaveSpin);
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_array,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);

        //save
        Button buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSavespin);
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SavePreferences("LIST", save);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView,
            View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        save = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(parentView.getContext(), "Result : " + save,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }


    /* Save password */
    public void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    /* Load password */
    public void LoadPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences data = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        loadedList = data.getString("LIST", "empty");
    }
}
```

Comment: check my ans. if u get right please accept it and upvote.

Comment: can you explain a little more exactly what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need shared preference to load values in spinner. You just need to declare array in string.xml file and load that. I am giving you my code. Just use it.:

## STEP-1:

### Declare array for spinner in your string.xml(res->values->strings.xml):--

```
<string-array name="country_array">
    <item>Greece</item>
    <item>United Kingdom</item>
    <item>Italy</item>
    <item>France</item>
    <item>Germany</item>
    <item>Turkey</item>
    <item>Poland</item>
    <item>India</item>
</string-array>
```

## STEP-2:

### Declare Spinner widget in your layout xml file

```
<Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinCountry"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     android:paddingLeft="8dp"
     android:popupBackground="@android:color/white"
     android:scrollbars="none"
     android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

## STEP-3:

### Declare Spinner in your Activity

```
Spinner spinCountry;
spinCountry= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinCountry);//fetch the spinner from layout file
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources()
                    .getStringArray(R.array.country_array));//setting the country_array to spinner
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinCountry.setAdapter(adapter);
//if you want to set any action you can do in this listener
spinCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long id) {
                  SavePreferences("LIST",spinCountry.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: how to save value string spinner?

Comment: sorry i m confused..what are you saying>?

Comment: how to store the value of the spinner using sharedpreference?

public void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {

Comment: pls see my update answer see setonitemselectedlistener.i put the new code savePreference("List",..)..

Comment: Thank you very much Kailash Dabhi, if for LoadPreferences () how?

Comment: just use loadPreference() where you needed it..!

Comment: SOLVED, but can not be called from another class?

Comment: cannot be called by another class means?what you want to call ?

Comment: SOlved, Spinner (Putint) Preference (Getint) ViewSpinner, thanks kailash

Answer (score -1):

U cannot use sharepreferences. Its stores very small piece of data, almost primitives not arrays values(objects). i hope u understood.

Comment: ok sush thank, solved

Comment: @XcziitcyurwkflfjkmNo then please upvote it na